# Unit test for a function in a function using CppUTeset

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, embedded, cpputest

How a unit test can be made for this kind of structure?
How to change the call so function `a()` will call function `mock_b()` instead of function `b()`.

```
// source.h
int b(int x);
bool a();


// source.cpp
int b(int x){return x;}
bool a(){return (b(5) > 0);}


// tester.cpp
#include "source.h"
int mock_b(int x){return -8;}

unit_test(){
    assert(true == a());
    b = mock_b;                 //How this replacement can be done?
    assert(false == a());
}
```

Comment: It is complicated, as your design is not good for separate tests. -- Don't test functions or methods separately, test features. -- You might want to search this site for duplicates of your question, unfortunately I don't have the time right now.

Comment: Generally you can do `#define b mock_b`.